# downloading rt.jar from prior java releases

Tags: java, rt.jar

Due to apache-tomcat 10 requirements, I need the "rt.jar" from Java 8 (possibly 7).
I need to compile my current stuff (I am on jdk 11) using "javac -source 8 -target 8 ..." (hoping not 7 here) but to do that right javac also needs "-bootclasspath somePathToRight/rt.jar".

Where can I find the jar file for Java8 (and 7) in case?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to compile your stuff to Java 8 exactly? Just yesterday I was able to install a servlet compiled with Java 18 into Apache Tomcat 10.0.23.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux or macOS, then tools like [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) and [ASDF VM](https://asdf-vm.com/) allow you to install multiple versions of Java at the same time. That way you can get `rt.jar` from the necessary version.

SDKMAN is more straightforward to use but ASDF VM is more extensible.

To get started with the latter you need to:

1. [Install ASDF VM](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html)
2. [Install the Java plugin](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java#install)
3. List available for installation JDKs: `asdf list-all java`
4. Install the necessary version. Something like `asdf install java adoptopenjdk-8.0.345+1`
5. The JDK will be installed to a directory like `~/.asdf/installs/java/adoptopenjdk-8.0.345+1`